# In outlook 2011, how can I get an occurrence event out of a series using applescript?

Tags: outlook, applescript

In outlook 2011 I try to use the following code to get a single occurrence out of a series of events, but it shows the error ""Microsoft Outlook got an error: The specified object is a property, not an element." number -10008". What went wrong?

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    activate
    tell calendar 3
        tell calendar event 1
            get occurrence of at date "Wednesday 29 April 2015 00:00:00"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a bug, this error occurs when the recurring of the event is false, or when the time of the date is wrong (must be the time of start date of the event) or no occurrence at this day.

Try this script, (change the subject in line 2)

```
set tdate to date "Wednesday 29 April 2015 00:00:00"
set event_subject to "some title"
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set myEvent to first calendar event of calendar 3 whose its subject is event_subject and its is recurring is true
    set sdate to start time of myEvent
    tell me to set time of tdate to time of sdate
    try
        set thisCalEvent to get occurrence of myEvent at tdate
    on error
        return "No occurrence of this event at " & tdate
    end try
    return thisCalEvent
end tell
```